# Going through a string multiple times while replacing parts of that string

Tags: rust, replace, borrow-checker

I have string that can look like this `"((a<=b)||(c&&(d==a))"`. Whitespace characters have been removed.
Now I need to find all solvable parts and replace them with something else. (I have chosen `"[i]"`, `i` increments per every replace)

So I expect the string to change like this `"((a<=b)||(c&&(d==a))"` ⇒ `"([0]||(c&&[1]))"` ⇒ `"([0]||[2])"` ⇒ `"[3]"`
I also need the individual parts to be captured.  So far I have written this function, with regex EXPR_RE for finding and capturing:

```rust
fn my_replace(in_str: &str) -> ([&str; 64], [[&str; 2]; 64]) {
    let mut operators: [&str; 64] = [""; 64];
    let mut operands: [[&str; 2]; 64] = [[""; 2]; 64];

    lazy_static! {
        static ref EXPR_RE: Regex =
            Regex::new(r"(\[?[A-Za-z0-9]+\]?)(==|&&|\|\||<=|!)(\[?[A-Za-z0-9]+\]?)").unwrap();
    }
    let mut i: usize = 0;
    let mut repl_line: String = in_str.to_string();
    loop {
        match EXPR_RE.is_match(&repl_line) {
            true => {
                for (_, [var_left, operand, var_right]) in
                    EXPR_RE.captures_iter(&repl_line).map(|c| c.extract())
                {
                    operands[i] = [var_left, var_right];
                    operators[i] = operand;
                    let orig_str = format!("({}{}{})", var_left, operand, var_right);
                    let repl_str = format!("[{}]", i);
                    repl_line = repl_line.replace(&orig_str, &repl_str);
                    i += 1;
                }
            }
            false => {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return (operators, operands);
}
```

The issue is that inside the `for`, which does the assigning and replacing, it won't let me assign to `repl_line` as it is borrowed in the `EXPR_RE.captures_iter(&repl_line)`. And I have no idea how to go around it or fix it.

I know that one pass works, since when I was testing the regex and replacing without going through the string multiple times, it worked and replaced correctly. The code looked like this:

```rust
fn _temp(in_str: &str) -> String {
    let mut operators: [&str; 64] = [""; 64];
    let mut operands: [[&str; 2]; 64] = [[""; 2]; 64];

    lazy_static! {
        static ref EXPR_RE: Regex =
            Regex::new(r"(\[?[A-Za-z0-9]+\]?)(==|&&|\|\||<=|!)(\[?[A-Za-z0-9]+\]?)").unwrap();
    }

    let mut i: usize = 0;
    let mut repl_line: String = in_str.to_string();
    for (_, [var_left, operand, var_right]) in EXPR_RE.captures_iter(in_str).map(|c| c.extract()) {
        operands[i] = [var_left, var_right];
        operators[i] = operand;
        let orig_str = format!("({}{}{})", var_left, operand, var_right);
        let repl_str = format!("[{}]", i);
        repl_line = repl_line.replace(&orig_str, &repl_str);
        i += 1;
    }

    return repl_line;
}
```

This has completed the first step correctly but I don't know how to make the more complete function `rec_replace` work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that your working code doesn't mutate `repl_line` in place. Instead it creates a new `String` with the replacement, drops the old `String`, and only then stores the new `String` in `repl_line`.

Comment: Oh, I see. So as a follow-up question, what would I use for mutating the string. If replace() doesn't mutate the string, what does?

Comment: I expect there is a solution with [`replace_all`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.10.2/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.replace_all) using a `FnMut` as `Replacer` and using `String` instead of `&str` for both `operators` and `operands`.

Comment: I am sorry about the wrong closing (), that's my fault. But replacing ```(a<=b)``` => ```[0]``` is correct. I don't want ```([0])```. And I don't understand what you mean by my regular expression missing an enclosing literal. Should the regex look like ```((some)(some)(some))```? Why would I capture all three captures I am doing?

Comment: Yea, enclosing `\(` `\)` is not necessary for your approach with reconstructing the `orig_string` and using `str::replace` my bad.

Comment: You should really parse this into an appropriate data structure that you can easily execute.

Comment: What do you mean by appropriate data structure? (Honest question)

Comment: If you don't need fast speed, an [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). If you do need it, [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode). And if you need extreme speed, maybe JIT it. Any option will be a lot faster than what you're doing now, and easier.

Comment: @PatrikHolub The suggestion is that this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) where the Y is "manipulate the string" and the X is "evaluate the expression contained in the string." If your actual goal is to manipulate the string, parsing it into an expression tree is going to make your overall goal of evaluating its contents _substantially_ easier in the long run.

Comment: I see. I was trying to do it the string way, since I am a beginner, which was in my original ask until cafce25 deleted that part. I heard of AST but it seemed way too complicated, but I will give it a try. (The project is for school and I need to know what is going on, even if it is a little bit slow). I know that a crate evalexpr exists, which would solve all my issues, but I can't use it.

Comment: @PatrikHolub Why can't you use that crate?

Comment: My teacher said I can't as I wouldn't know how it evaluates the entire expression. He told I should make something myself.

Comment: I looked into AST but, I am afraid that would completely wreck me. It would require to begin the project anew after spending a bunch of time on other things. If I say that performance isn't important, as this will have to do at most 128 replacings. Can someone help me make repl_line approach work? From what I can gather I can't use the repl_line for replacing because the ```capture_iter()``` borrows it. Can I somehow go around it with ```clone()```

Comment: @PatrikHolub You still need some way to actually evaluate the expression. If you haven't yet learned in the course how to write a tokenizer, parser, and AST model then it sounds like the assignment is not a good one. Have you asked your teacher what concepts he expects you to apply to solve the problem?

Comment: @cdhowie Well, the assignment isn't part of a programming course, so I am on my own. The evaluation I have made already. Assuming I can get the basic ```a?b``` as a string. Given left and right and using match for the operator, I can make an evaluation using just string. But the issue is getting those strings. The teacher just said to make my own boolean evaluator. Nothing much more. I asked him about the evalexpr crate and he said no to that one.